# InformixDB 2.5: symbol SQLSTATE: referenced symbol not found

Tags: python, informix, symbols, importerror, relocation

I successfully installed Python2.5.6 and InformixDB2.5 on Solaris 10 Sparc

When I run a Script I get the following Error:

```
import informixdb

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/informixdb.py", line 146, in <module>
    from _informixdb import *
ImportError: ld.so.1: python2.5: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so: symbol SQLSTATE: referenced symbol not found
```

`ldd -d /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so` gave me the following output:

```
libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/libsocket.so.1
        libdl.so.1 =>    /lib/libdl.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
        libgcc_s.so.1 =>         /usr/sfw/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
        libscf.so.1 =>   /lib/libscf.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
        libdoor.so.1 =>  /lib/libdoor.so.1
        libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/libuutil.so.1
        libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/libgen.so.1
        symbol not found: SQLSTATE              (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: PyExc_StandardError           (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: sqlca         (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: _Py_ZeroStruct                (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: SQLCODE               (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: PyType_GenericNew             (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: PyType_GenericAlloc           (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: PyExc_ImportError             (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: PyList_Type           (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: PyBuffer_Type         (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: _Py_NoneStruct                (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: PyExc_StopIteration           (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: PyType_Type           (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: _Py_TrueStruct                (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: PyExc_TypeError               (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: PyObject_Free         (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        symbol not found: PyBool_Type           (/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/_informixdb.so)
        /platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T1000/lib/libmd_psr.so.1
        /platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T1000/lib/libc_psr.so.1
```

I haven´t found a solution yet or a similar problem.

Anyone got an idea of how to fix this?

Greetings

Comment: I see that InformixDB is old. It is from 2007 and can work only with Python 2.5. If I want to use Python and Informix I work with Python and ODBC (it can work on Linux, so I hope it can work on Solaris too) or with Jython and JDBC driver (I have found Informix JDBC driver more reliable than ODBC). Maybe you can workaround your problem by changing technology?

Comment: InformixDB might be old, but the same Version works under Windows without any problems. Python Scripts are already made to work with InformixDB. The easiest way would be to get InformixDB to work under Solaris.

Comment: InformixDB implements DB API, so it would be easy to switch to ODBC or even JDBC (with `zxJDBC` module).